# How can I train a CRF on two datasets with CRF++?

Tags: crf, crf++

I have two datasets: dataset A and dataset B. I want to use [CRF++](https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170320151625/https://taku910.github.io/crfpp/)) to train a conditional random field (CRF) on dataset A, then train the CRF on dataset B. Is it possible to achieve that with CRF++?

I do not want to train the CRF on two datasets at the same time.

Comment: Your question makes no sense. Do you want two different models? If you don't want two different models, why do you think combining your datasets is inappropriate?

Comment: @polm23 combining isn't good because I want a model that is specialized for one data set

Comment: Then just train two different models. `crf_learn templateA trainA modelA` then `crf_learn templateB trainB modelB`.

Answer (score 0):

I think its absolutely possible to train 2 individual models ( one on dataset A and another on dataset B ).

In case you want only 1 model , then you can combine both datasets and train 1 model.

If I was unable to answer your question, then I'm not sure what you are trying to do. Could you please elaborate your doubt?

Comment: Thanks. What they want to do is: train a conditional random field (CRF) on dataset A, then train the CRF on dataset B. Training the CRF on both data sets at once would achieve a different result.